# Too few items for a table?

Tags: database, database-design

I am creating a website and one of the things the user should specify is his/her country. I suppose there are around 200 countries. Which approach is better- storing the 200 countries in a List/Array in the application(therefore a bit more RAM usage) or storing them as a table in the database? How are these kind of problems generally solved?

Comment: Define "better". Just use the database the way it was intended. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."--Knuth

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Answer (score 1):

A 200-row table is not bad practice per se. The main issue is the technical complexity of having your country column be a foreign key to this table. Do countries come and go on a regular basis? Do they frequently change names in a way that requires centralizing all the names in a single table?

My usual approach is to simply store the [country's two-letter country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) in a `char(2)` column. This gives you the ability to quickly infer the actual country's name (as opposed to checking what country ID 37 means) without actually introducing an extra table, extra join.

Now, if your application is actually centered on such a country's data, it makes sense to have a country table with several columns to store information about the country, but then I would advocate using the two-letter country code as primary key for that table.

Answer (score 1):

Having a small number of rows is not an issue. If a table is small the database server can cache the whole thing in memory. Databases are fine with small tables.

If you store the countries in a table you can always set up an application level cache that keeps a copy of the contents in memory. It’s easy to add new entries in the database when needed, you can set the expiration time on the cache so new entries can get picked up.

My preferred way to build an application is to have an application-level cache that is separate from the application code so that I can tweak it without code changes. That way I know I can tune the cache later without changing code and I don’t have to code with caching in mind.